# temporarily change default shell inside a perl system call

Tags: shell, perl

Here's the situation...
In perl, I run this...

```
 my $stat = system("cd somewhere && source somescript.bash && do_something_else");
```

For all my users, except one, this is not a problem.  But for the one guy, this is a problem because it sources somescript.bash using tcsh, not bash. I have no control over  somescript,bash.  IOW, I can't stick #!/usr/bash in line 1.  I can't just "bash somescript.bash" because it sets env vars that do_somethiung_else needs.

I need to "source" that script in bash but just in the context of this one perl system call.  I don't want to leave this guy with an altered environment when the perl script is done.  My best guess is to somehow temporarily change the default shell, but I don't know how to do that.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Perl's `system` is [hardcoded to use `sh -c`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/63afdf6c0f65af480aa5bb9ccba9f46dae52f6fc:/doio.c#l2378). I'm not sure how you're getting that to run tcsh instead.

Comment: @ikegami Unfortunately it doesn't come from runtime. I replaced both entries in Config_heavy.pm and it only affected `perl -V:sh`, but not the execution of pipes. There is also `SH_PATH` in header files which I'm afraid compiled-in into binary... :(

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, there's an environment variable that system / exec will use to determine the default shell, but I think there's a more straight forward way:

```
my $stat = system('/bin/bash', -c => 'cd somewhere && source somescript.bash && do_something_else');
```

That is, call bash, and give it the commands you want. On systems that default to bash anyway, this is pretty much what perl is doing under the covers. On the one system that the default isn't working on, it'll force the issue.

Comment: Very curious.  This failed....               
system( " '/bin/bash', -c => 'cd some_real_dir' ")                 
Error "No such file or dir"             
This worked...               
system("cd some_real_dir")

Comment: @ikegami thanks, I knew my memory of such was rusty, and there was obviously a reason why I pushed it out of my mind: it never affected me anyway :)

Comment: Same result without the comma.              
/bin/bash exists.          
The "No such file or directory" points right at the dir I'm trying to cd to.

Comment: No, seriously, run the command the way I wrote it. Don't add extra quotes around the whole thing.

Comment: Just checked `PERL5SHELL` doesn't work in Cygwin :(

Comment: @midenok, I did say it only works in Windows. Cygwin is a unix emulation environment. Anyway, it makes no sense to want to change which shell system uses. It will break code. If you want to run a command with a specific shell, launch that specific shell as shown in the answer.

Comment: @ikegami I know what is Cygwin! Since it is under Windows they could support this. You are a bit hurrying about "makes no sense". Pipe subshell via /bin/sh doesn't support native-style path (c:\...) and native execution from the compiled binary doesn't support mixed-style path (c:/...). When the existing software uses both of the above from the same value one of them must be changed. Since changing C code of multi-platform tool to handle that quirk is absolutely unfeasible the only solution is to fix subshell. I already made wrapper over /bin/sh and it works like a charm.

Comment: @midenok, Re "*Since changing C code of multi-platform*", No need to change any C code. If you want to run a `cmd` command, tell `system` to launch `cmd`. Again, read the answer.

Comment: @midenok, Re "*Pipe subshell via /bin/sh doesn't support native-style path (c:\...)*", More importantly, `cmd` doesn't support `sh`'s syntax. So changing the shell used by `system` would break all the code that passes `sh` commands to `system`.

Comment: @midenok, Re "*You are a bit hurrying about "makes no sense"*", No. You wouldn't be able to pass a shell command to `system` if the shell used was unpredictable or in someone else's control, because you wouldn't know how to write the command. So again, that makes no sense. Even in Windows, it only makes sense to use `PERL5SHELL` to tell Perl where to locate `cmd`.

Comment: @ikegami You telling non-sense. Shell is under your own control of your script. You know what you're doing if you need to use different shell.

Comment: @ikegami If you are so smart for giving universal solutions, maybe you will provide simpler solutions for that: https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commits/bb-10.4-midenok (commits marked by MDEV-30836) I know you won't and I know you can't, because your solutions are not possible there.

Comment: @ikegami No questions to you.

Comment: @midenok, If you have a question, [ask it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). // Re "*because your solutions are not possible there.*" I never said they were. *You* are the one who said you needed to run a shell command using `system`. If you're wrong about that, I would have no way of knowing.

Comment: @@midenok, Re "*No questions to you.*", Yes. That's my point. You should not be asking me questions, especially not in the comments of what you claim is some unrelated Q&A. The proper place is using the "[Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)" button.

Comment: @ikegami You started to talk with me and you started giving evident things when nobody asked you to. I just wanted you to know talking evident things is useless.

Comment: @midenok, wut. You replied to two of my 4-year old comments. Don't lie when it's so easy to verify!

Comment: @midenok Re "*Shell is under your own control of your script.*", Yes, it can be. But you were hoping you could get around that using some environment var. Like I said, that would be bad. It should be up to Perl or the script. It should not be out of the script's control, cause then the script won't know what language to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254866/discussion-between-midenok-and-ikegami).